# JSF page with dialog loads data multiple times from database

Tags: jsf, jpa, jsf-2, primefaces, dialog

I have a JSF page where there is a Primefaces data table.
So of the rows can have a extra data, which I want to display in a dialog.

When I load the page the data is retrived twice from the database
This is log messages when get data from the database.

```
14:11:44,004 INFO  [stdout] (http-localhost/127.0.0.1:8080-1) LogMessageProducer.getAllMessages:600 ms
14:11:44,325 INFO  [stdout] (http-localhost/127.0.0.1:8080-1) LogMessageProducer.getAllMessages:165 ms
```

When I press the Dialog link,
This is log messages when get data from the database.

```
14:17:26,135 INFO  [stdout] (http-localhost/127.0.0.1:8080-1) LogMessageProducer.getAllMessages:203 ms
14:17:26,416 INFO  [stdout] (http-localhost/127.0.0.1:8080-1) LogMessageProducer.getAllMessages:156 ms
14:17:26,712 INFO  [stdout] (http-localhost/127.0.0.1:8080-1) LogMessageProducer.getAllMessages:203 ms
14:17:27,024 INFO  [stdout] (http-localhost/127.0.0.1:8080-1) LogMessageProducer.getAllMessages:187 ms
14:17:27,306 INFO  [stdout] (http-localhost/127.0.0.1:8080-1) LogMessageProducer.getAllMessages:187 ms
14:17:27,602 INFO  [stdout] (http-localhost/127.0.0.1:8080-1) LogMessageProducer.getAllMessages:187 ms
14:17:27,852 INFO  [stdout] (http-localhost/127.0.0.1:8080-1) LogMessageBodyProducer.getOnId:156 ms
14:17:28,164 INFO  [stdout] (http-localhost/127.0.0.1:8080-1) LogMessageProducer.getAllMessages:187 ms
14:17:28,430 INFO  [stdout] (http-localhost/127.0.0.1:8080-1) LogMessageProducer.getAllMessages:171 ms
14:17:28,711 INFO  [stdout] (http-localhost/127.0.0.1:8080-1) LogMessageProducer.getAllMessages:187 ms
```

Before the Dialog box is displayed.

Why?
The JSF page looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ui:composition xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"  xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core" xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html" xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui" template="/WEB-INF/templates/default.xhtml">
   <ui:define name="content">
    <h:form id="form">   
      <p:dataTable var="_msg" value="#{logMessageProducer.allMessages}" reflow="true" rows="50" paginator="true" paginatorTemplate="{CurrentPageReport}  {FirstPageLink} {PreviousPageLink} {PageLinks} {NextPageLink} {LastPageLink} {RowsPerPageDropdown}"
                         rowsPerPageTemplate="25,50,100,500,1000"
                         tableStyle="table-layout: auto;">            
         <p:column headerText="Id"><h:outputText value="#{_msg.id}" /></p:column>         
         <p:column headerText="CorrelationId"><h:outputText value="#{_msg.correlationId}" /></p:column>
         <p:column headerText="Timestamp"><h:outputText value="#{_msg.timestamp}" /></p:column>         
         <p:column headerText="State"><h:outputText value="#{_msg.state}" /></p:column>
         <p:column headerText="Host"><h:outputText value="#{_msg.host}" /></p:column>
         <p:column headerText="Message"><h:outputText value="#{_msg.message}" /></p:column>
         <p:column style="width:16px" headerText="File">
            <p:commandLink value="Link" oncomplete="PF('test').show()" update=":form:dialog" rendered="#{not empty _msg.fk_body_id}">
                    <f:setPropertyActionListener target="#{mbean.selectedLogMessageBody}" value="#{logMessageBodyProducer.getOnId(_msg.fk_body_id)}" />
            </p:commandLink>            
        </p:column>

      </p:dataTable>
      <p:dialog modal="true" width="500" height="500" widgetVar="test" id="dialog" header="File">            
           <p:panelGrid  columns="2" columnClasses="label,value" style="table-layout: auto;">
               <h:outputText value="Filename:" />
               <h:outputText value="#{mbean.selectedLogMessageBody.fileName}" />
               <h:outputText value="Extension:" />
               <h:outputText value="#{mbean.selectedLogMessageBody.extension}" />
               <h:outputText value="Size:" />
               <h:outputText value="#{mbean.selectedLogMessageBody.fileSize}" />
               <h:outputText value="Filelink:" />
               <h:outputText value="#{mbean.selectedLogMessageBody.fileLink}" />                        
           </p:panelGrid>            
      </p:dialog>      
    </h:form>      
    </p:panel>
   </ui:define>
</ui:composition>
```

Comment: If this has been answered before, could u please provide a link, I can not figure out the solution for this.

Comment: Found it at the top, sorry

Comment: I also asked [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29884821/unexpected-jpa-select-statements-logged-when-jsf-page-submitted) a few days ago, user1073857. You might find that interesting.